# How to open vim and edit file from C program?

Tags: c, neovim

I have this simplified program where I try to open a file in my home directory from a C program. The system() function opens the file normally, but when I use execvp(), nvim opens a blank screen (no text is showing). Am I using execvp wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* arguments[] = {"/home/test/test.txt", 0};
    execvp("nvim", arguments); //This doesn't work
    system("nvim /home/test/test.txt"); //This works

    return 0;
}
```

It seems like when I use execvp, the argument list isn't used.

Answer (score 3):

By convention, the first argument to a program (which will become `argv[0]`) is the name of the program.  So your arguments should be:

```
char* arguments[] = {"nvim", "/home/test/test.txt", NULL};
```